# Grails GORM: how to link tables by a composite foreign key?

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

I have a default audit_log table from [audit-logging](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) plugin which looks like this:

**audit_log:** `id | class_name | event_name | ...`

I want to provide a human-readable description for logged events. I decided to add another table with descriptions:

**audited_event:** `id | class_name | event_name | description`

and map these descriptions to the first table on `class_name` and `event_name`.

I have the following domain class:

```
class AuditLog {

Integer id;
String actor;
String className;
Date dateCreated;
String eventName;
Date lastUpdated;
String newValue;
String oldValue;
Integer persistedObjectId;
String persistedObjectVersion;
String propertyName;
String uri;
AuditEvent event;

static mapping = {
    table 'audit_log';
    version false;
    cache usage: 'read-only';

    id column: 'id';
    actor column: 'actor';
    className column: 'class_name';
    dateCreated column: 'date_created';
    eventName column: 'event_name';
    lastUpdated column: 'last_updated';
    newValue column: 'new_value';
    oldValue column: 'old_value';
    persistedObjectId column: 'persisted_object_id';
    persistedObjectVersion column: 'persisted_object_version';
    propertyName column: 'property_name';
    uri column: 'uri';

}
```

but I don't know how to write mapping for the `AuditEvent event`. Here I want to use the existing fields `class_name | event_name` as a composite foreign key to link with `audit_event` table. Will appreciate your help.

upd: assume AuditEvent has fields `auditedClass` and `event`

Comment: Can you include a link to this "data-auditing" plugin? Nothing comes up using that search term on grails.org.

Comment: @Stuporman, sorry, it was audit-logging! Here: http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging I'll update the post

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll have to study this plugin, but if no one else gets an answer before I've figured it out, I'll do my best to get you an answer.

Comment: BTW, the reason I want to study this is that I've found through personal experience that I usually can't answer my own question because I've approached the problem from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I really understood your question, but from the question `how to write mapping for the AuditEvent event`, I think you can map the `AuditEvent` class separately, just as what you have done to class `AuditLog`:

```
Class AuditEvent {
    String auditedClass
    String event
    String description
    ....

    static mapping = {
        table 'audited_event'
        auditedClass column: 'class_name'
        event column: 'event_name'
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I asked about. I want the `event` field to be initialized at the time `AuditLog` is loaded. I.e. I want to join the the `AuditEvent` table and load the `event` object.

Comment: All right, you can define Event as an [embedded](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/embedded.html) property.